Why was Feynman asked about boundary values and initial values when he was beginning to describe his quantum computer?
The 1982 publication of a polished transcript of Richard Feynman's 1981 Endicott House keynote lecture on simulating physics with computers is often considered, at least in the West, to be of foundational importance in the history of the field of quantum computing. In the talk, Feynman initially ponders how difficult it would be to simulate quantum mechanics even with a probabilistically classical machine, but posits that a quantum computer would be effective at doing such a task, if only one could be built. It's as if Feynman anticipated that BPP$\subsetneq$BQP, and further that Hamiltonian simulation might be just such a problem splitting the two.  The talk is a tour-de-force about computer science as understood by a bunch of physicists in the early 80's, and is recommended reading for many interested in the field.
But even more than forty years on there are still some portions of the talk that have puzzled me.  In particular, we have the following enigmatic exchange shortly after Feynman started broadly describing a cellular automaton to simulate Hamiltonian dynamics:

Question: "Doesn't this reduce to the ordinary boundary value, as opposed to initial-value type of calculation?"
Answer: "Yes, but remember this is the computer itself that I'm describing."

Although the publication silent as to who asked Feynman this question in 1981, I suspect it was Charlie Bennett himself (who Feynman otherwise credits throughout in his talk). Indeed, when Daniel Harlow was describing the primacy of software over hardware in a 2017 IFQ Complexity talk at about the four-minute mark, Bennett asks Harlow a very similar question - enquiring "Is this the same or related to the distinction between initial conditions and laws of motion?" Harlow responds less curtly than Feynman was but even then, I couldn't quite grasp the point of the question.
So, why did the (anonymous) asker propose that Feynman's efforts to simulate time with a cellular automaton reduced to an initial/boundary value problem, and what did Feynman mean in his response?
Is there anything meaningful that can be said about this 40-over year old interaction, or is it lost to the sands of time?

I think big part of why such question could be because at time theoretical physics revolved around those type of problem solving.

@MattiSarjala can you expand on this into an answer?

Ok. I'll spent some time to think about this.

Bennett is alive. Ask him.

Thanks, I might do that. Bennett appears warm and welcoming but I’m a  nobody, and little intimidated still to ask an ~80 yo gentleman about something he might have said more than 40 years ago.


It's as if Feynman anticipated that BPP⊊ BQP

Yes. In similar fashion than if one states that computer that uses chaos
for computing can solve Navier-Stokes in linear time. Assuming our theories in physics are correct.

So, why did the (anonymous) asker propose that Feynman's efforts to
simulate time with a cellular automaton reduced to an initial/boundary
value problem, and what did Feynman mean in his response?

Feyman start to talk about cellular automaton, but switch to more general topic:
"But just let's us think of a more general kind of
computer, because we might have a more general function. So let's talk
about whether we could have a wider case of generality of interconnections
of points in space-time. If F depends on the points both in the future and the past, what then?"
Initial-value type of calculation is how cellular automaton works. And question: "Isn’t this situation like a boundary-value problem, where you solve for the entire system based on constraints at the edges"

That might makes sense - cellular automata was all the rage back then. The conference was well attended by cellular automata enthusiasts such as Bill Gosper, as well as Fredin and Toffoli. I guess there was a lot of hunting for "Garden-of-Eden" configurations, etc.
